# Prove a family of function is equi-continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_n(x)=\sin \sqrt{x+4n^2x^2}$ on $[0,\infty)$.
>
> (1) Prove that $f_n$ is [equi-continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity) on $[0,\infty)$.
> (2) $f_n$ is uniformly bounded.
> (3) $f_n \to 0$ pointwise on $[0,\infty)$
> (4) There is no subsequence of $f_n$ that converges to $0$ uniformly
> (5) Compare with the [Arzela-Ascoli Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem).

Below is the definition of equi-continuous.

[image]

Does this problem mean equi-continuous at a point or uniformly?

Could someone give me some hint? Thanks！

Comment: You have a problem at $0:$ $f_n(1/n)-f_n(0)$ does not converge to $0.$

Comment: @Why $f_n(1/n)-f_n(0)$ does not converge to 0? I thought it is convergent to 0. Could you please tell me the reason why it is not convergent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the last sentence of the first paragraph you quote: "The family is equicontinuous if it is equicontinuous at every point of $X$."  Here $X = [0,\infty)$.  So you would need to show that for every $x_0 \in [0,\infty)$ and every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for every $n$ and every $x$ with $|x-x_0| < \delta$, we have $|f_n(x_0) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon$.

However, zhw's comment shows that this does not hold when $x_0 = 0$, so in fact the family is not equicontinuous on $[0,\infty)$.  Since $f_n(x) = \sin\left(\sqrt{x + 4 n^2 x^2}\right)$, we have $f_n(1/n) = \sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} + 4}\right)$ and $f_n(0) = 0$.  As $n \to \infty$, by continuity of $\sin$ and $\sqrt{\cdot}$ we get $|f_n(1/n) - f_n(0)| \to \sin(2) \ne 0$.  So choosing some $\epsilon < \sin(2)$, for every $\delta > 0$ we can choose $n$ so large that $1/n < \delta$ and so that $|f_n(1/n)| > \epsilon$, and taking $x = 1/n < \delta$ we have $|f_n(x) - f_n(0)| > \epsilon$.

Comment: Why $f_n(1/n)-f_n(0)$ does not converge to 0? I thought it is convergent to 0. Could you please tell me the reason why it is not convergent?

Comment: @Sherry: I added an explanation.  Is it possible you have copied the question incorrectly?

Comment: Although I copied it incorrectly, your explanation give me hint. Thanks!